# Validate numeric text field in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in jquery to prevent non-numeric characters being inputted to the text field

```
$("#NumericField").numeric();
```

Now, on the text field i cant input non-numeric characters. That is OK. The problem here is if the user will paste on the text field with non numeric characters.

Is there a way/method to disable pasting if the value is non-numeric? Or is there any other approach to handle this situation that you can share?

Comment: You should better use a class instead of an ID to identify all numeric fields. Now you can only have a single numeric field on a page.

Comment: Good idea. I will change my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use callback which checks on leaving field if value is valid if value is not valid then clear it and show error message:

```
var decimal_char = ',';
function isvalidnumber(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    //This regex is from the jquery.numeric plugin itself
    var re=new RegExp("^\\d+$|\\d*" + decimal_char + "\\d+");
    if(!re.exec(val)){
        alert("Invalid number");
        $(this).val("");
    }       
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtN").numeric(decimal_char,isvalidnumber);
});
```

Comment: Maybe instead of an error message the input could just be filtered to remove the illegal characters? It could be nicer for the user if he/she pastes a number that has a space in the end, for example.

Comment: I've modified it. first one was not working and not taking into account decimal char

Comment: @borato this was just to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

I found this script on http://www.kunalbabre.com/jQueryLibrary/index.php:

```
$('input[numeric]').keyup(function() {    
    var d = $(this).attr('numeric');

    var value = $(this).val();
    var orignalValue = value;
    value = value.replace(/[0-9]*/g, "");

    var msg = "Only Integer Values allowed.";

    if (d == 'decimal') {
        value = value.replace(/\./, "");
        msg = "Only Numeric Values allowed.";
    }

    if (value != '') {
        orignalValue = orignalValue.replace(/([^0-9].*)/g, "")
        $(this).val(orignalValue);
        //alert(msg);
        $(this).after('<span style="margin-left:5px;color:red;position:absolute;">' + msg + '</span>');
    } else {
        $(this).next('span').remove();
    }
});
```

It works fine except if the number has ',' on it like '100,000.00'. It will render just '100'. The ',' and the rest are gone.

Edit: I think this is on the reg ex but im clueless about it. :(

Any Idea? Help?

Comment: Please add this code of line before adding the span $(this).next('span').remove(); The reason behind is that text becomes darker and darker so better to remove span before adding.

Answer (score 1):

Where it says:

```
value = value.replace(/\./, "");
```

You should put:

```
value = value.replace(/\.\,/, "");
```

I guess ;-)

I really ended up doing this:

```
$(‘.InputClass’).keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val() != "")
     $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "") );
});
```

So, no anoying alerts nor anything; just if you type anything else than a number or a dot after a number, is wipped out. Simple but efective.

Cheers. Hope helps someone.